# How to set default SQL options for all SQL queries in OpenLink Virtuoso

Tags: virtuoso

Currently I actively exploit a very attractive ability of Virtuoso to define SQL views using SPARQL. When I use these views in a composite SQL query without any Virtuoso-specific options,
the execution time is enormously large. So, additional options should be included at the end of each query, like

`SELECT COUNT(*) from V1 JOIN V2 ON V1.s = V2.d .....` **`option (loop, order)`**

Is there a way to configure Virtuoso by a such manner, that the options clause will be added automatically and the SQL query itself will not include it ?

Answer (score 0):

The query options like `loop` and `order` (as well as `index`) are fine-tuning hints for Virtuoso's built-in SQL optimizer; as such, they cannot be set globally (because they should not be).

Some queries may indeed work better with these set, but this certainly will not apply for *every* SQL query; in fact, in most cases, their use would produce worse execution plans. If you compose a SQL query and find Virtuoso does not make an optimal plan, this is when such on-demand fine tuning can be appropriate.

That said, it would be very helpful if any SQL queries that are producing worse execution plans were reported to us ([OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me) via the [OpenLink Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com/) for any edition of Virtuoso and/or a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/) for the Open Source Edition (a/k/a VOS), so we can look into them and possibly improve or fix the query optimizer.